# Run Xunit and UI Tests test from code with reflection

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests, xunit

I am trying to run CodedUI Tests from MTM as well as running Xunit tests on our code base.  I am supposed to be able per my requirements to run these tests from ONE project so as to be able to gather data on the tests later on.  I have been able to get the tests to run in both instances from the same code using reflection to call test methods based on their respective attributes.

The problem is, then for both the UI and the Xunit tests, the Test Explorer is not registering that the tests are passing or failing.  I assume that there is some initialization that must occur for the testing environment, but I can't find any resource on it.

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CodedUITestProject1;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting;
using CodedUITestProject2;
using System.Reflection;
using ConsoleApplication1;

namespace Run_UI_From_Outside
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

// This section uses reflection to find Test Methods in the CodedUITest class bases on their attributes
            var assembly = typeof(CodedUITestProject2.CodedUITest1).Assembly;
            var attributes = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CodedUITestProject2.CodedUITest1), true);
            var types = assembly.GetTypes();

            foreach (var t in types)
            {

                var ca = t.CustomAttributes;
                foreach (var item in ca)
                {

                    if (item.AttributeType == typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestAttribute))
                    {

                        object myInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                        MethodInfo myInstanceMethod = t.GetMethod("CodedUITestMethod1");
                        Playback.Initialize();
                        var test = myInstanceMethod.Invoke(myInstance, null);
                        Playback.Cleanup();
                    }
                }
            }


//  This section uses reflection to find Xunit Methods in the CodedUITest class bases on their attributes
            var assemblyXunit = typeof(ConsoleApplication1.Tests.SampleTest).Assembly;
            var xunitMethods = assemblyXunit.GetTypes().SelectMany(t => t.GetMethods())
                .Where(a => a.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Xunit.FactAttribute), false).Length > 0)
                .ToArray();


            foreach (var t in xunitMethods)
            {
                    object myMethodInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(t.DeclaringType);
                    t.Invoke(myMethodInstance, null); 
            }



        }
    }
}
```